# How was 78557 originally suspected to be a Sierpinski number?

Tags: number-theory, math-history

A [Sierpinski number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number) is an odd number $k$ such that $k2^n+1$ takes only composite values. **In 1962, Selfridge proved that $78557$ is a Sierpinski number.** It remains the smallest known such number.

How was $78557$ originally suspected to be a candidate for proving this property? The year 1962 lies at the dawn of the age where *some* computer-based search might have been possible, but I would be surprised if that were the case.

Comment: *How was $78557$ originally suspected to be a Sierpinski number?* - He had that weird look in his eyes, like he was hiding something...

Answer (score 4):

The remainders of $k2^n+1\pmod{p}$ repeat for any prime $p$.
If $k=2\pmod3$ then $k2^n+1$ is a multiple of 3 for even $n$; if $k=1\pmod3$ then $k2^n+1$ is a multiple of 3 for odd $n$.
If $k=1\pmod5$ then $k2^n+1$ is a multiple of 5 for $n=4m+2$.
And so on.  What he did was to find a set of $p_r$ and residues $b_r$ so that they covered every value of $n$.
Choose $k=2\pmod3$ and $k=3\pmod5$, and you have covered all but $n=1\pmod4$.
After $p=17$ you have all but $n=1\pmod8$ because $17|2^8-1$.
After $p=7$ you have all but two residues $\mod 24$
After $p=13$ you have all but one residue $\mod 24$
After $p=241$ you have all $n$ covered.
There are some choices in the residue classes.  For any set $k=\{b_r\pmod p_r\}$, use the Chinese remainder theorem to find $k$.