# Is there always a prime number in these sets?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Let $a$ be a natural number greater than $1$.

Consider the sets $ S(a):=\{f_n(a); n\in \mathbb{N}\}$,

with $f_0(a):=a$,  $\ \ f_1(a):=2a-1\ \ $ and for $n>1$,  $\ \ f_n(a):=f_1(f_{n-1}(a))$ .

> Question: Is there always a prime number in $S(a)$, whatever $a$?

This question is raised, because for some $a$, the smallest prime in $S(a)$ can apparently be quite big, and it may take a large $n$ to find it.

Examples:

With $a = 95$, the first prime in $S(95)$ is reached when $n=582$, and it is a $178$ digits prime.
\begin{align*}f_{582}(95)=
&148793969526219687690798316645419749525135019619289042892300334\\
&545486970624089571289662346878443815865741959129891309426553781\\
&2046389415279164757669092989298186306341246574002177\end{align*}

With $a = 767$, the first prime in $S(767)$ seems to be a huge $1928$ digits prime.

Any reference on this question is also welcome.

As @lulu pointed out, $S(a)= \{ (a-1)2^n +1)\}$ is a set of *Proth numbers*.

So the question is equivalent to whether there exists a *$k$-Proth prime*, i.e. a prime of the form $k\cdot2^m+1$, for any odd $k$.

Comment: Aren't these sets of the form $\{(a-1)\times 2^n+1\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$?  If so, I doubt it is known whether or not the set always contains a prime.

Comment: @lulu,  right.  Then these are Proth numbers. I will edit my question in order to mention this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the primes of the form $k\times 2^n+1$ has been studied and it is known that there are integers $k$ such that $k\times 2^n+1$ is never prime. They are called [Sierpinski number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number).

The smallest proven Sierpinski number is $78557$ because $78557\times 2^n+1$ is always the multiple of $3, 5, 7, 13, 19, 37$ or $73$. Distributed computer search is ongoing and there are only $5$ numbers such that $k<78557$ and no explicit $a_k$ such that $k \times 2^{a_k}+1$ is found. Also you can read more on the answers of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1085334) and other related questions.

Comment: Didn't know this, thanks! (+1)